# solution $y$ of ODE satisfies $y(x)<0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $c(x)\in C^1([a,b])>0, d(x)\in C([a,b])\geq 0, f\in C([a,b])<0$ and let $y$ be a solution of
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{ll}
-c'(x)y'(x)-c(x)y''(x)+d(x)y(x)=f(x) & x\in(a,b) \\
y(a)=a_0<0 ,y'(b)=b_0<0\\
\end{array}
.
\end{align}
Show that $y(x)<0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.
My first idea was to show that $y'(x)<0$ because this means $y$ is strictly decreasing and because of $y(a)<0$ I get $y(x)<0$. But I think it is not true that $y$ is strictly decreasing. Thaks for any hints.

Answer (score 2):

Assume by contradiction that $y(x) < 0$ $(x\in [a,b])$ is not true. Let $x_0 \in [a,b]$ be such that
$$
y(x_0) = \max_{x\in [a,b]} y(x).
$$
By assumption $y(x_0) \ge 0$. Since $y(a) < 0$ we have $x_0 \not=a$. Since $y'(b) < 0$ the solution ends strictly decreasing, hence $x_0 \not= b$. So $x_0 \in (a,b)$, hence $y'(x_0)=0$ and $y''(x_0) \le 0$. Thus
$$
f(x_0) < 0, ~~~~ c(x_0)y''(x_0) \le 0, ~~~~ -d(x_0)y(x_0) \le 0.
$$
From the ODE we get
$$
0=f(x_0)+c(x_0)y''(x_0)-d(x_0)y(x_0) < 0, 
$$
a contradiction.